# Error adding images on GoogleMaps API v3 InfoBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add images on the  infoBox inside of many markers using GoogleMaps API v3.

The code is working fine before trying to add images (omiting the indicated code).

Peace Javascript Code on HTML page:

> ```
> function LoadMapa(value)
> {    
> var idInfoBoxAberto;
> var infoBox = [];
> function abrirInfoBox(id, marker) {
>     if (typeof(idInfoBoxAberto) == 'number' && typeof(infoBox[idInfoBoxAberto]) == 'object') 
>     {infoBox[idInfoBoxAberto].close();
>     }
>     infoBox[id].open(map, marker);
>     idInfoBoxAberto = id;
>     }
> initialize(value);
> function initialize(value) {
>   var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
>   var mapOptions = {
>      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-3.7280,-38.5303),
>      zoom: 12,
>      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
>     }
>     var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
>     var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
>     var markers = [];
>     //BUILDING MARKERS
>     $.each(value, function(i,e) {
>      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>             map: map,
>             draggable: true,
>             position: new google.maps.LatLng(new Number(e.latitude), new Number(e.longitude)),
>             title: e.nome_posto_saude,
>              visible: true
>         }),
>         boxText = document.createElement("div"),
>         //these are the options for all infoboxes
>         myOptions = {
>             content: boxText,
>             disableAutoPan: false,
>             maxWidth: 0,
>             pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
>             zIndex: null,
>             boxStyle: {
>             background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
>             opacity: 0.75,
>             width: "280px"
>             },
>             closeBoxMargin: "12px 4px 2px 2px",
>             closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
>             infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
>             isHidden: false,
>             pane: "floatPane",
>             enableEventPropagation: false
>         };
>         //define the text and style for all infoboxes
>         boxText.style.cssText = " border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background:#333; color:#FFF; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; padding: 5px; border-radius:6px; -webkit-border-radius:6px; -moz-border-radius:6px;";
>         //TEXT BOX CUSTOMIZATION            
>         var BoxElements = "<h3  font-weight: bold; text-align:center;>"+e.nome_posto_saude + "</h3><br>" + "Resposta 1:"+e.lista_respostas[0] + "<br>" + "resposta 2:"+e.lista_respostas[1]+ "<br>" + "resposta 3:"+e.lista_respostas[2]+ "<br>" + "resposta 34:787878";
>         var imagesElements = "";
> //<------------------- IF I OMIT THIS PART BELOW ALL WORKS!!!!!! ------>            
>       //OBTAINING IMAGES_pATH_LIST:
>         var image_url = "get_images_path/"+e.id;
>         var imagesLoaded = false;   
>    $.getJSON(image_url,function(data1,innerData){
>       for( var y=0; y<3;y++)
>       {
>         if(typeof data1[y] != "undefined")
>          {
>             imagesElements += "<img class=\"picture\" th:src=\"@{/image/"+data1[y]+"/}\" style=\"width: 5px; height: 5px;\"></img>";
>           }
>        }     
>        boxText.innerHTML = BoxElements + imagesElements;
>        alert(BoxElements + imagesElements);
>             });
>  //<--------------IF I OMIT THIS PART ABOVE ALL WORKS! ----------_> 
>      boxText.innerHTML = BoxElements + imagesElements;
>      infoBox[new Number(e.id)] = new InfoBox(myOptions);
>      infoBox[new Number(e.id)].marker = marker;
>      var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
>      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
>      boxText.innerHTML = BoxElements + imagesElements;
>      ib.open(map, this);  // change the map variable appropriately
>     });
>   markers.push(marker);
>   latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
>  });
>    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
>    map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
>   }
>  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
> }
> ```

So, omiting the indicated code for adding images, the HTML page shows something like this when i click on a marker:

[image: All the info is displaying OK]

If I add this peace of code, i will do getJSON obtaining the image_path for each marker, and i will add these images using the `innerHTML` with the `imagesElements` code:

```
//TEXT BOX CUSTOMIZATION            
var BoxElements = "<h3  font-weight: bold; text-align:center;>"+e.nome_posto_saude + "    </h3><br>" + "Resposta 1:"+e.lista_respostas[0] + "<br>" + "resposta 2:"+e.lista_respostas[1]+ "<br>" + "resposta 3:"+e.lista_respostas[2]+ "<br>" + "resposta 34:787878";
var imagesElements = "";

//OBTAINING IMAGES_pATH_LIST:
var image_url = "get_images_path/"+e.id;
var imagesLoaded = false;   
$.getJSON(image_url,function(data1,innerData){
    for( var y=0; y<3;y++) {
        if(typeof data1[y] != "undefined") {
            imagesElements += "<img class=\"picture\" th:src=\"@{/image/"+data1[y]+"/}\" style=\"width: 5px; height: 5px;\"></img>";
        }
    }   

    boxText.innerHTML = BoxElements + imagesElements;
    alert(BoxElements + imagesElements);
});
}
```

This alert shows me that the imagesElements code is correct (the getJSON for obtaining the image source is received OK by the getJSON but no image is displayed neither my Spring Server doesn't receive any request).

Note: I am working with Thymeleaf, but I have tested with the HTML `<img>` code and it doesn't work:

> ```
> imagesElements += "<img class=\"picture\" src=\"@/image/"+data1[y]+"/\" style=\"width: 5px; height: 5px;\"></img>";
> ```

Which is my mistake? maybe the InfoBox doesn't supports Images inside?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you appending a slash (/) to data1[y] in your src attribute?

Comment: @maurice Thank you for your annotation but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Alterto Crespo - Was mostly curious, but worth a shot changing it, I think. I've mostly seen 'src' attributes that don't start with an '@' and end with a slash. As a sanity check, I would have set 'src' to a fixed name instead of loading from a variable -- literally and figuratively reduce the number of variables that could go wrong.

Comment: @Maurice - Thank you man, it works using your recomendation:
`imagesElements += "<img class=\"picture\" src=\"/image/?id="+data1[y]+"\" style=\"width: 40px; height: 40px;\"></img>";`

But the biggest problem was that I didn't know that getJSON works asynchronously, is why the variable didn't update in the right time.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that getJSON works asynchronously, so to solve the issue i have to put all the code inside of the getJSON.